# Find max and min of a column and update the first column sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

Based on the product and product key, update the column ord_by. There should be only one min  and max for a product and product_key .

```
E.g: Table


  +-------------+---------+-------+--------+
| Product_key | product | price | ord_by |
+-------------+---------+-------+--------+
|           1 | ABC     |    10 |        |
|           1 | ABC     |    10 |        |
|           1 | ABC     |    20 |        |
|           1 | ABC     |   100 |        |
|           1 | ABC     |   100 |        |
|           2 | EFG     |    20 |        |
|           2 | EFG     |    40 |        |
|           3 | ABC     |   100 |        |
+-------------+---------+-------+--------+

Expected output:
+-------------+---------+-------+--------+
| Product_key | product | price | ord_by |
+-------------+---------+-------+--------+
|           1 | ABC     |    10 | Min    |
|           1 | ABC     |    10 | Mid    |
|           1 | ABC     |    20 | Mid    |
|           1 | ABC     |   100 | Mid    |
|           1 | ABC     |   100 | Max    |
|           2 | EFG     |    20 | Min    |
|           2 | EFG     |    40 | Max    |
|           3 | ABC     |   100 | None   |
+-------------+---------+-------+--------+
```

My try :

```
;WITH ord_cte
            AS (
                SELECT product
                    ,product_key
                    ,max(price) as max_price
                    ,min(price) as min_price
                FROM t_prod_ord

                group by   product,product_key

                )
            UPDATE t1
SET ord_by = case 
when t2.max_price =t2.min_price then 'none' 
when t2.max_price=t1.price then 'max' 
when t2.min_price=t1.price then 'min'  
else 'mid' end 
            FROM t_prod_ord t1
            INNER JOIN ord_cte t2 ON t1.product_key = t2.product_key   and t1.product=t2.product
```

using this query it is updating more than one max and min value for column ord_by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate row number for each `Product_key` order by `Price` in both `ASC` and `DESC` order. Then use the row number in `CASE` statement to find the `Min/Max` values

`Count() Over()` aggregate window function will help you find the total count of each `Product_key` which we can use it for finding `None`

Here is one way

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY Product_key ORDER BY price) AS Min_KEY,
                Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY Product_key ORDER BY price DESC) AS Max_KEY,
                Count(1)OVER(partition BY Product_key) AS cnt
         FROM   Yourtable)
SELECT Product_key,
       product,
       price,
       CASE
         WHEN cnt = 1 THEN 'None'
         WHEN Min_KEY = 1 THEN 'Min'
         WHEN Max_Key = 1 THEN 'Max'
         ELSE 'Mid'
       END
FROM   cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do with out cte...

```
 SELECT [Product_key],
           [product],
           [price],
           CASE
           WHEN Max(RN)
                    OVER(
                      PARTITION BY PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT
                      )=1 AND RN=1 THEN 'NONE'
             WHEN Min(RN)
                    OVER(
                      PARTITION BY PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT
                     ) = RN THEN 'MIN'
             WHEN Max(RN)
                    OVER(
                      PARTITION BY PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT
                      ) = RN THEN 'MAX'

             ELSE 'MID'
           END ORDER_BY
    FROM   (SELECT *,
                   Row_number()
                     OVER(
                       PARTITION BY PRODUCT_KEY, PRODUCT
                       ORDER BY PRICE) RN
            FROM   TABLE1)Z
```